# Matlab: Signal spectrum is similar, but xcorr shows not similar

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectrum

I have two signals, which has similar spectrum, see the chart1.
But when I do `xc = xcorr( signal1, signal2 )`, the result is not similar. see chart2 ( `plot(abs(xc))` ).

Is it true that for similar signals, we should get the `xcorr` result as chart3?
Anything I need to pay attention for `xcorr`?

[image: chart1][image: chart2][image: chart3]

Comment: [This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60790/autocorrelation-of-a-uniform-random-process/60804#60804) is related to your problem,

Comment: Chart 3 is for almost identical signals. Chart 2 shows the cross-correlation between signals with the same low-frequency content but very different mid- and high-frequency content (e.g. dominated by noise).

Answer (score 0):

`xcorr` returns the cross-correlation between two signals but without any adjustment of the length or amplitude. Nevertheless, you are right that there should be a clear peak. Correct the offset and it should work smoothly. `xcorr` can do this automatically if you specifiy the `xcorr(...,scaleopt)`-option:

> **scaleopt — Normalization option**
>
> 'none' (default) | 'biased' | 'unbiased' | 'normalized' | 'coeff'

Note that your signals need to have the same length for this. What you also may want to add is the `maxlag` attribute to reduce the calculation and the amount of allowed shifting.

Comment: It is hard to understand from the charts what we see because there are no legends, units or axis labels. However, you can have to noisy datasets with a similar (broad-band) frequency pattern, which will have no cross-correlation with one another